# Tweaking on keyup event to call API once it appears user has finished typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, user-input, client-side

I have a postcode field that has a jQuery onKeyup event - the idea is that once they have fully entered their postcode to call an Google Maps Geocoding API to get the location immediately based on this postcode.

This code works however i'd like to find a solution that will ideally not call the API multiple times but wait and see if the user has finished typing using some method of waiting for x amount of time and then calling the API.

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

```
$("#txtPostcode").keyup(function() {
    var postcode = $('#txtPostcode').val().length
    if (postcode.length >= 5 && postcode.length <= 8) {
        console.log('length is a valid UK length for a postcode');
        // some logic here to run with some way to work out if user has 'finished' typing
        callGoogleGeocodingAPI(postcode);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debounce function in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787768/debounce-function-in-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to only make the call after typing has stopped for 250ms - this is generally enough time between keystrokes to allow the full entry. Try this:

```
var timer;
$("#txtPostcode").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var postcode = $('#txtPostcode').val().length
        if (postcode.length >= 5 && postcode.length <= 8) {
            console.log('length is a valid UK length for a postcode');
            // some logic here to run with some way to work out if user has 'finished' typing
            callGoogleGeocodingAPI(postcode);
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

You can tweak the exact timeout to better suit your needs if you feel there is too much of a delay.

Comment: Thanks - this works and has minimal changes required!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional decorator that will delay the event until the last keypress. You can play with the delay time to get the best feel. 200ms is an arbitrary value.

```js
$("#txtPostcode").keyup(delayEvent( function( e ) {
  
  console.log( 'event fired' );
  // this refers to the element clicked, and there is an issue with in the if statement
  // you are checking postcode.length.length which probably throws an error.
  var postcode = $(this).val();
  if (postcode.length >= 5 && postcode.length <= 8) {
    console.log('length is a valid UK length for a postcode');

    // some logic here to run with some way to work out if user has 'finished' typing
    // callGoogleGeocodingAPI(postcode);
  }
}, 200));

// this is a functional decorator, that curries the delay and callback function
// returning the actual event function that is run by the keyup handler
function delayEvent( fn, delay ) {
  var timer = null;
  // this is the actual function that gets run.
  return function(e) {
    var self = this;
    // if the timeout exists clear it
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    // set a new timout
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      return fn.call(self, e);
    }, delay || 200);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtPostcode">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using .blur() instead of .keyup() in your code, if you haven't tried already.