# textarea not submiting on pressing enter the second time after the first submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a textarea that submits when the input field is not empty. Assuming I want to prevent multiple submission on pressing the enter key simultanouesly with the following, it only submits each time I refresh the page. this is the code:

```
window.formWasSubmitted = false;

    document.getElementById('new-input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13 && $.trim($(this).val()) && !window.formWasSubmitted) { // enter key press     && $(this).val().length > 0
            e.preventDefault();
            window.formWasSubmitted = true;
            send();
        }
        //window.formWasSubmitted = false;
    });
```

please how can I allow the textarea to submit without refreshing the page on entering data each time

Comment: You have a condition !window.formWasSubmitted which refrains you from submitting again since you have already set it to true. You may remove that condition, I don't see a reason why you need it

Comment: Yes! If I remove it on pressing the enter keyboard multiple times, it submits the same content in the textarea as much as those times

Comment: Well shouldn't the textbox only post when enter key is pressed ? That's typically how it works

Comment: yes, it should but on pressing it like 5 times at once, it posts the same contents five times

Comment: Then you need to set the flag to true in your send() method and also should clear the text field.

Comment: So if you can give me any idea to prevent that, I will remove that line of code.

Comment: Something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/pmd78erg/

Comment: i want to debounce the enter key after the first time press

Comment: In your scenario, the question is when or which enter key should actually submit the data. In my opinion, you should have a separate button to submit the data

Comment: so how did skype, did the trick

Comment: skype sends the text everytime enter key is pressed

Comment: yes it does, but enter some text, lets say -hi- then try to hit enter like three times at once, it posts -hi- only once

Comment: that is my challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want to debounce the enter key. Is that correct? Since you're using JQuery, take a look at this: [Debounce function in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27787768/64279)

Comment: yes. I want to debounce the enter key after the first time

Comment: Then I believe all you need to do is get rid of the `window.formWasSubmitted` code and change `send();` to `$.debounce(250, send);`

Comment: If I press the enter key simultaneously three times, it sends the contents three times, so it does not debounce

Comment: OK, I think you have to assign the result of the debounce function to a variable like `var sendDebounced = $.debounce(250, send);` OUTSIDE of the event handler and then inside the event handler you'd use `sendDebounced();`.