# How to trigger only one jQuery event with a muti-selector?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am targeting multiple elements with a jQuery selector by classname, and would like to:

1. Fire the event of the first item only
2. Ignore all other selector items

Here is a humorous vertical menu which demonstrates the problem, which if moused-over fast will fire concurrent events and behave like a slinky.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(".child").hide();
  $(".parent").on("mouseover", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.siblings(".parent")
      .find("ul")
      .slideUp();
    $this.find("ul")
      .slideToggle();
  });
})();
```

```css
#sidebar,
li {
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">Menu 1
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 2
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 3
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 4
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try using e.stoppropagation();

Comment: Have you attempted a debounce? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787768/debounce-function-in-jquery

Comment: @crai -- thank you for the advice, however I have tried `e.stopPropagation()`, and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` with no such luck.

Comment: @Jerinaw -- have never heard of this, thanks for the information! Reading [the documentation about this plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/ "jQuery debounce by Ben Alman"), there is a statement -- "*when called repetitively, executes the original function just once per "bunch" of calls*", which seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mouseover` use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and it works fine

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(".child").hide();
  $(".parent").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    
    $this.find("ul")
      .slideToggle();
  });
})();
```

```css
#sidebar,
li {
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">Menu 1
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 2
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 3
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 4
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: With `mouseleave` in place, each item becomes self-closing and `$this.siblings(".parent").find("ul").slideUp()` can be omitted.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks for the reminder. Edited the code

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseover`/`mouseout` events have a particular behaviour with regard to child elements.

- `mouseover` triggers when the cursor enters an element from outside, or from a child element.
- `mouseout` triggers when the cursor leaves an element, either by leaving it to the outside or by entering a child element.

This is not always the behaviour you want, so jQuery provides two synthetic events :

- `mouseenter` triggers only when the cursor enters an element from outside.
- `mouseleave` triggers only when the cursor leaves an element to the outside.

The odd "slinky" behaviour observed in the question is caused by the `mouseover`/`mouseout` behaviour, by which the event handler fires each time the cursor enters parent elements from the outside but also when it re-enters from child elements.

The simplest change would be to replace `mouseover` with `mouseenter`, thereby responding only to cursor entry from outside the parent elements.

That will give something more like the behaviour you would expect.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(".child").hide();
  $(".parent").on("mouseenter", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.siblings(".parent")
      .find("ul")
      .slideUp();
    $this.find("ul")
      .slideToggle();
  });
})();
```

```css
#sidebar,
li {
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">Menu 1
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 2
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 3
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Menu 4
      <ul class="child">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As the other answer indicates, you can also attach the handler to the `mouseleave` event, thereby ensuring that the menu system collapses reliably regardless of how the cursor leaves each of the parent elements.