# Search functionality not working well (laravel, ajax, jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a search functionality on my app where the table updates whenever the user types on the input box. I have made it working, however, I encountered some weird issue where:

1. If I type on the search box fast, I get a 500 (Internal Server
   Error).
   [image]
2. When I delete the search text by holding the backspace on the
   keyboard, sometimes, the display table is not updated (it's being
   updated only once I start searching again).

   All records are **4 in total**. When I searched **"one one"** and deletes the search text by holding the **backspace** keyboard key, I only get **2** records instead of **4**, sometimes only **1** record. But if I only press the **backspace repeatedly**, I get all the records.

[image]

If I type normally or delete the search text's character one by one, I don't encounter the issue.

This is my ajax call through jquery:

[image]

This is my controller:

[image]

This is the method on my model (Applicant::search()) that handles the search:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the 500 error in the DevTools to see what the error is? You probably need to find a denounce to prevent a submission after every character change see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787768/debounce-function-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787768/debounce-function-in-jquery), I'm not a jQuery guy, so I don't know if the function had been deprecated.

Comment: The error only states that there's an error message. I added the debounce, and it now works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to add debounce or pass a delay function.

```
$('#search_applicant').on('input', _.debounce(function (e) {
   // your ajax here
}, 300)); // set your delay here
```

Refer to this [link](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Comment: I've used debounce, thanks for this. I've updated my jquery like this for future reference:

$("#search-applicant").on("input", $.debounce(200,function(){
  var search_text = $(this).val();
  var container = $(".list tbody");

  $.ajax({
   url: '/applicants/search',
   method: 'GET',
   data: {
    skey: search_text
   },
   success: function(result){
    container.empty().append(result);
   }
  });

  console.log(search_text);

 }));