# Skip a delayed event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to skip a delay event in JavaScript. Say( If I mouse wheel for 4 times continuously the first one ill get fired followed by the second, third and fourth one. In my scenario if the first event fired and when the second/third/fourth events are in delay or slow I want to speak the second and third event getting fired and must directly fire the final event (say fourth event))

Is this possible using JS/Jquery! And can anyone suggest me some sample for it if possible!

Sorry if I don’t make much sense, I am a beginner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a debounce function, which will fire on the first event but merge subsequent events within a defined timeframe.

This plugin should achieve what you're looking for: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787768/debounce-function-in-jquery) may also be helpful.

Based on the autocomplete example on this page, http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/, the final (4th in your example) event should be fired, but any intermediate events that happen in quick succession will be skipped.

[Here is a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-eyheaf), debouncing a mousewheel event to every 0.1s. You simply need to include the plugin and then do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', $.debounce(100, debounceEvent));
    function debounceEvent(event) {
        // Process mouse wheel event here
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

If you do a quick scroll, only the last event should be emitted.

Comment: Yes! @Matt Saunders. I can ignore the event but how can I call the final event which is triggered!

Comment: I think the final emission should work, if you give it a try. If you look at the 'pretend autocomplete' option on here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/ The final text input is displayed, it just skips any events that happen in quick succession between the first and last event.

Comment: Have added an example @NoobDeveloper - let me know how you get on.